# Json parsing (.net 4.0)

Tags: c#, json, .net-4.0

I am using c# and framework .Net 4.0, I did a good research but unable to parse this json as this is a bit strange. Please help Thanks:

```
[ 
  { 
    "tp": [ "one_owner","used" ],  
    "mk": [ "cadillac" ], 
    "md": "", 
    "yr": "", 
    "pr": "", 
    "co": "", 
    "fe": "", 
    "bd": "", 
    "en": "", 
    "tn": "", 
    "ml": "", 
    "dt": "", 
    "fl": "", 
    "st": "", 
    "postType": "BT", 
    "visitorid": 1, 
    "websiteid": 1, 
    "flag": 0, 
    "actionurl": "", 
    "pid": "", 
    "datetime": "2014-03-31T13:17:54.623Z"
  }, 
  { 
    "tp": [ "new" ], 
    "mk": [ "cadillac" ], 
    "md": "", 
    "yr": "", 
    "pr": "", 
    "co": "", 
    "fe": "", 
    "bd": "", 
    "en": "", 
    "tn": "", 
    "ml": "", 
    "dt": "", 
    "fl": "", 
    "st": "", 
    "postType": "BT", 
    "visitorid": 1, 
    "websiteid": 1, 
    "flag": 0, 
    "actionurl": "", 
    "pid": "", 
    "datetime": "2014-03-29T13:41:27.336Z"
  }, 
  //moreee elements like above
]
```

---

Comment: You should show code of how you "tried" to parse this.

Comment: JSLint says that's bad JSON - www.jslint.com

Comment: try use 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<objctType>("jsonValueHere");

Comment: have you tried JSON.net ?

http://json.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I see is you have an extra comma at the end of your object:

The end of the object (`"datetime": "2014-03-29T13:41:27.336Z" }, ]`) should instead be `"datetime": "2014-03-29T13:41:27.336Z" } ]`, without the comma.

Results from [jslint.com](http://jslint.com):

```
Unexpected character '(space)'.  [ { "tp": [ "one_owner","used" ], "mk": [ "cadillac" ], "md": "", "yr": "", "pr": "", "co": "", "fe": "", "bd": 

line 2 character 114Unexpected character '(space)'.
"", "en": "", "tn": "", "ml": "", "dt": "", "fl": "", "st": "", "postType": "BT", "visitorid": 1, "websiteid": 1, 

line 3 character 108Unexpected character '(space)'.
"flag": 0, "actionurl": "", "pid": "", "datetime": "2014-03-31T13:17:54.623Z" }, { "tp": [ "new" ], "mk": [ 

line 4 character 114Unexpected character '(space)'.
"cadillac" ], "md": "", "yr": "", "pr": "", "co": "", "fe": "", "bd": "", "en": "", "tn": "", "ml": "", "dt": "", 

line 5 character 109Unexpected character '(space)'.
"fl": "", "st": "", "postType": "BT", "visitorid": 1, "websiteid": 1, "flag": 0, "actionurl": "", "pid": "",
```